# Rearranging a column based on a list order and then mapping the list as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I need to map a list as a new column in a dataframe based on another column with the same values but may have different cases fro different letters:

```
        Input DF (df_temp):
        Name  Class
        ABC   1
        EFG   2
        HIJ   3
        ABC   4
        
        param_list:
        ['AbC', 'EfG', 'HiJ']

        Output DF (df_temp):
        Name  Class  DB_Name
        ABC   1      AbC
        EFG   2      EfG
        HIJ   3      HiJ
        ABC   4      AbC
```

I have written a small piece of code using 2 for loops but is there a better way to the same:

```
        for param in param_list:
            for i in range(len(df_temp.Param_Name.str.lower().tolist())):
                if param.lower() == df_temp['Name'][i].lower():
                    df_temp['DB_Name'][i] = param
```

Comment: Are the values in Name always uppercase?

Comment: No not necessarily

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created in dict comprehension and `lower`, if some value not match get missing values, if need replace them by original `Name` values add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
L = ['AbC', 'EfG', 'HiJ']
d = {x.lower():x for x in L}

df_temp['DB_Name'] = df_temp['Name'].str.lower().map(d)
#if possible some values not match
#df_temp['DB_Name'] = df_temp['Name'].str.lower().map(d).fillna(df_temp['Name'])
print (df_temp)
  Name  Class DB_Name
0  ABC      1     AbC
1  EFG      2     EfG
2  HIJ      3     HiJ
3  ABC      4     AbC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`:

```
s = pd.Series(L, name='DB_name', index=map(str.upper, L))
df_temp = df_temp.assign(k=df['Name'].str.upper()).join(s, on='k').drop('k', 1)
```

Result:

```
  Name  Class DB_name
0  ABC      1     AbC
1  EFG      2     EfG
2  HIJ      3     HiJ
3  ABC      4     AbC
```

Comment: Column "Name" will not necessarily have capital letters, the alphabets can be of any case, lower or upper, does this handle this case as well?

Comment: @Anonymous I didn't knew that! by the way edited the answer